# Android download file error

Tags: android, download

```
public class Downloader {
    public static String getWebPage(String URLString) {
        String retVal = "";
        try {
            // Perform action on click
            URL url = new URL(URLString);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            // Get the response
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                retVal += line + "\n";
            }
            rd.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // Print out the exception that occurred
            retVal = "Invalid URL " + URLString + ": " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            retVal = e.getMessage();
        }
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

The above code works well on the emulator 2.3.1. When I try to execute the same on either the emulator 3.x.x or on my Motorolla XOOM, the code does not work.  It does not produce any errors but returns blank text. Any idea how I can fix this?

NB: I have included the following in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Does it read anything ? How does your code get out from loop ? (Btw, consider using a StringBuilder for String concatenation), and why not using Apache IOUtils.readLines ?

Comment: You should also print the stack trace in case of exception

Comment: It works fine on the emulator if i set the adroid version to 2.3.1. The problem starts when I try to execute it on a 3.x.x version of android whether its emulator or device.  If fails when it executes the following line

  BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));

Answer (score 0):

> use this dude
>   public class Downloader {

```
    public static void DownloadFile(String fileURL, File directory) {
            try {

                    FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(directory);
                    URL u = new URL(fileURL);
                    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    c.setDoOutput(true);
                    c.connect();

                    InputStream in = c.getInputStream();

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                    int len1 = 0;
                    while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                            f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    }
                    f.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

}